# Spring Boot: Get required columns from API based on user request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

**I am trying to implement an API endpoint where a user can request required columns from the API**

Basically, this is what I want:
This is my products table entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="products") 
class product{
   private Long id;
   private String itemName;
   private String itemDesc;
   private double quantity;
   private double purchaseRate;
   private double saleRate;
   private double onlineSaleRate;
.
.
.
constructor()
getter & setter
}
```

***And my endpoint is:
`localhost:8080/api/v1/products`

Requirement:
*I want to write an api endpoint where i request columns based on requirementsa and get those as response*

Example: If i only need - itemName, itemPrice and quantity i'll return those as response only.
if some user has requirement of itemName, purchaseRate, saleRate, quantity he will get those as a response only.

Right now i am writing new endpoints as per requirements, but i think there is some way to do this.

**I want to implement this in my application, i tried google for this but there is no search query that is resulting me as per my requirement.**

Comment: @SyedMustafaHussain This does not help my requirement, this is a guide on how to write rest api.

Comment: You can achieve that using JsonViews, https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation. Keep in mind that you should Implement that yourself this approach. It is not plug-and-play. Your requirement is not also trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with all the fields of your entity with the field types of nullable boxed Boolean (for the purpose of the request json).

```
class ProductColumns {
    private Boolean itemName;
    private Boolean itemDesc;
    ...

    // setters and getters
}
```

Then, to construct a custom response, you can use a java Map to acheive this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getFilteredColumns(ProductColumns columns) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if (columns.getItemName() == true) {
        map.put("itemName", [your repo/service method for getting the particular value]);
    }
    if (columns.getItemDesc() == true) {
        map.put("itemDesc", your repo/service method for getting the particular value]);
    }

    ...

    return ResponseEntity<Object>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Of course you should wrap it in some `try-catch` to your liking.

Comment: thanks for your response. This will do the work for now.